# Is Multiple grouping possible in SPGridView?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Is it possible to have multiple grouping in SPGridview? Grouping is working fine for a single column? Is there any way to have multiple grouping in SPGridView programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [definitive guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx) on SPGridView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using SPGridView.

From what I've found out, the grouping is based on setting the `SPGridViewRow.HeaderText` property. I think I used Reflector to figure this out.

Unfortunately, SPGridViewRow is a sealed class. If you can figure out any way to get around this let me know.. The only thing I can think of is to inherit from GridView and rewrite all the SPGridView functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a nested gridview user control in ASP.NET http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/article.php/c12647/ and host the user control in a web part.

protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();
            try
            {
                this.Controls.Clear();
                GridViewWebUserControl = this.Page.LoadControl("~/_controltemplates/WebPart1/GridViewWebUserControl.ascx");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                err = e.Message;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Not is possible multiple grouping in SPGridView.

I'm the suggest, that you are use

http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm

SPGridView is good the following scenario:

One Group with SPDataSource and SPList.